# How a browser based Form POST becomes a Server Side event like Button_OnClick

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have seen this question in [What Great .NET Developers Ought To Know -By Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)

I am not very sure, but as per my knowledge a button control gets rendered as HTML with input tag as submit(with a dynamic Id). When a POST event is fired ASP.Net uses dynamically generated button ID and matches respective button click event at C# side....

Please let me know, if my understanding is correct. Thought it can be completely wrong or out of context.

UPDATE:-

I did little google and came across [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1832994.aspx/1) link 
Which states as

> An ASP.NET Button control in HTML is an HTML input element with a type
>   attribute set to "submit".  A submit button in HTML invokes a POST,
>   using the action attribute from the form element, which, for ASP.NET,
>   is the current page.  Since this is a POST, the form variables are
>   populated with all of the values from the input elements in the form
>   element, including the value (name) of the submit button.  When the
>   POST arrives at the server and is parsed by ASP.NET, it will
>   acknowledge that the POST was initiated by the submit button, which is
>   turned into a Click event for the original ASP.NET Button control.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apologies, if i have created confusion. I just want to know the answer to question-"Describe how a browser-based Form POST becomes a Server-Side event like Button1_OnClick?"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating simple ASP.NET single page app with multiple buttons?
You can do that and then inspect the output page in browser.
You shall see hidden field __EVENTTARGET with value of button id that makes submit, on every postback this hidden field travels to server as well as __VIEWSTATE.
Maybe this is the 'answer'?

Answer (score 1):

An ASP.NET Button control in HTML is an HTML input element with a type attribute set to "submit".  A submit button in HTML invokes a POST, using the action attribute from the form element, which, for ASP.NET, is the current page.  Since this is a POST, the form variables are populated with all of the values from the input elements in the form element, including the value (name) of the submit button.  When the POST arrives at the server and is parsed by ASP.NET, it will acknowledge that the POST was initiated by the submit button, which is turned into a Click event for the original ASP.NET Button control.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Web Forms applications, a variety of events, often click events, post a form back to a server. The event is a message such as "Button1_OnClick", which is bound to a method (i.e. event handler) by 
an event delegate.

The following code sample has a `System.EventHandler` object that binds the `Button1_OnClick` method to the `Button1.Click` event.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_OnClick);
}

private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```